# Lunar surface illumination levels

Tags: the-moon, planetary-science, photography, astronomy, sunlight

I am trying to determine the lunar surface near or far side daytime illumination levels in Lux or foot-candles but there seems to be no directly measured values available. I did find this information on the levels as measured from earth, so it should be possible to work backwards to arrive at those values I presume. My math is very rusty indeed though, so thought I'd put the question to some experts. How bright is moonlight? https://academic.oup.com/astrogeo/article/58/1/1.31/2938119

Comment: You'll want to look at [vol 51 no 5](http://bstj.bell-labs.com/BSTJ/images/Vol51/bstj51-5-955.pdf) of the *Bell System Technical Journal*.  Appendix A (pp. 1055-1073) is entirely about lunar light.

Comment: I see [you've followed my advice](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/lunar-surface-illumination#comment70828_35853), but I realize that I should have said something about deleting it there first. In Stack Exchange cross-posting the same question in multiple sites is strongly discouraged, one reason is that it leads to answer fragmentation. It's a good idea to delete one of these instances. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the title to "radiance" because "illumination" is not strictly a physics term and could be confused with "irradiance," the amount of light hitting the moon.

Answer (score 2):

> Illumination of the moon's surface at night in full earth is 15-17lx

Magazine "Техника кино и телевидения" 1972, #5, page 44
http://www.planetology.ru/panoramas/selivanov_i_dr_1972_tevizionnye_sistemy_panoramnogo_obzora.pdf?language=russian

> The camera was equipped with an automatic sensitivity adjustment system, which ensured the transmission of high-quality images in the illumination range from 80 to 150,000 lux.

FIRST PANORAMAS of LUNAR SURFACE. Publishing House "Nauka", Moscow, 1966
http://epizodsspace.airbase.ru/bibl/ziv/1966/6/89-z-1b.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately my Russian skills are worse than my math skills. I did find some information in English from "The measurements of sky brightness on Lunokhod-2" and from NASA "Lighting Constraints on Lunar Surface Operations"